# Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched around and did see a question about this error however I can still not seem to manage to find the right way to write it, I keep getting an error for this code, what is wrong with the group by?

```
SELECT
    orders.customerid, orderdetails.orderid, 
    AMOUNT = unitprice * quantity 
FROM 
    orderdetails
JOIN 
    orders ON orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid 
GROUP BY 
    orders.customerid, orderdetails.orderid
```

Error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'xyz' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @vc74 if this is SQL server that's valid syntax - my bet is that you are trying to group by customerid and orderid without using an aggregate on unitprice or quantity. Don't you want to `SUM(unitprice * quantity)`?

Comment: @vc74 The syntax is fine either way. Surely the problem is we're multiplying two values that aren't in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That syntax is invalid ANSI SQL.

Comment: The clue is that MSSQL returns this error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1` - usually followed by `Column 'xyz' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @jarlh But valid syntax for the query and database in question. Definitely isn't the problem here. Actually these days I prefer the `COLUMN = VALUE` syntax as it's much easier formatting to read with all the columns in the same left position as opposed to varied lengths on the right side of the value.

Comment: @JacobH, The <sql> tag says "_If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._"

Comment: @david Oha Just remove `group by`, it will execute, use Gordon's query if u want to see at aggregate level

Comment: @jarlh I'm aware of how tags work, the error message is MS SQL though. Kind of silly to assume the error is coming from another rdbms right?

Comment: @JacobH, how could I know? I know ANSI SQL pretty well, but not Microsoft SQL Server...

Comment: @jarlh There were two comments before yours stating that the syntax was fine?

Comment: @JacobH, "_if this is SQL Server_" followed by "_The syntax is fine either way_", which I read as regardless of dbms!

Comment: @jarlh yeah but SQL Server is MSSQL :) - even though it just sounds like .. a SQL server?! Damn Microsoft!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `group by`, but no aggregation functions.  That is the first hint that something is wrong.  You have columns in the `select` that are not being aggregated.  That is a bigger hint.

I would also rewrite the query using table aliases:

```
select o.customerid, od.orderid, sum(od.unitprice * od.quantity)
from orders o join
     orderdetails od
     on o.orderid = od.orderid 
group by o.customerid, od.orderid;
```

But, if I had to speculate, I'm guessing you want the sum at the *customer* level, not the *order* level, so:

```
select o.customerid, sum(od.unitprice * od.quantity)
from orders o join
     orderdetails od
     on o.orderid = od.orderid 
group by o.customerid;
```

Comment: That works, I forgot I needed to have some aggregation element.
However just so I understand, whenever I group by, all the other columns that do not contain an aggregate element have to be mentioned under the group by?

Comment: @DavidOha Yes correct - unless if it is hardcoded value